# Parse 64bit hex numbers

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am using spirit X-3 and want to parse RAM addresses that are represented in hex, like "00ff0af0".
For 64 bit systems the addresses would have a size of 64 bit.

Unfortunately `boost::spirit::x3::hex` uses unsigned.

What can I do to parse 64 bit hex numbers with boost-spirit?

Comment: You can easily cast between signed/unsigned right? What's the issue? Besides why would you use signed integers for that? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Would this work: `uint_parser<boost::ulong_long_type, 16, 1, 16> hex_p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to see if this works:

```
uint_parser<boost::ulong_long_type, 16, 1, 16> hex_p;
```